# Adding information to the database Parse.com error PFObject

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I have some trouble passing data between parse and user ID facebook , I have this error below :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or
>   values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.

Can you help me please !

My code between `FacebookSDK` and parse to get the information from users

```js
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        
        self.Username.delegate = self
        self.Name.delegate = self
        self.emailUser.delegate = self
        self.genderUser.delegate = self
        
        //import data from facebook
        
        
        
        let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, gender, email"])
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler( {
            
            
            (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            
            if error != nil {
                
                print( error)
                
                
            } else if let result = result {
                
                PFUser.currentUser()?["gender"] = result["gender"]
                PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] = result["name"]
                PFUser.currentUser()?["email"] = result["email"]
                
                
                PFUser.currentUser()?.save()
                
                
                
                let userId = result ["id"] as! String
                
                
                
                let facebookProfilePictureUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=small"
                
                if let fbpicUrl = NSURL(string: facebookProfilePictureUrl) {
                    
                    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fbpicUrl) {
                        
                        self.imageUser.image = UIImage(data: data)
                        
                        let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: data)
                        
                        
                        
                        PFUser.currentUser()?["image"] = imageFile
                        PFUser.currentUser()?.save()
                        
                        //Insert info user in profile
                        
                        
                        self.Name.text = PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] as? String
                        self.genderUser.text = PFUser.currentUser()?["gender"] as? String
                        self.emailUser.text = PFUser.currentUser()?["email"] as? String
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error says, either one of these lines are assigning nil to the PFUser object:

```
PFUser.currentUser()?["gender"] = result["gender"]
PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] = result["name"]
PFUser.currentUser()?["email"] = result["email"]
PFUser.currentUser()?["image"] = imageFile
```

Find out which of the values in result are nil and take action accordingly. Since Parse doesn't support the object pointer 'nil', you will have to use `[NSNull null]`.

**EDIT**

I'm pretty new to Swift myself but here is a possible solution to your problem. You could for instance do a check like this:

```
PFUser.currentUser()?["gender"] = result["gender"] ?? NSNull()
```

This includes a ternary operation to the assignment, which basically says 'if result["gender"] is not nil, then return it, else return NSNull()'. This solution is of course only valid if you don't mind that Parse objects have NSNull() values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm new in swift, what do I have to change in my code ? thank you so much